# How to check if a specific Character is first in a string read from a file in bash

Tags: string, bash, grep, raspberry-pi

I'm writting a basic installationhelper for my software to install it on a Raspberry Pi. So far, I'm reading which packages I have to install from a textfile line by line. I would like to be able to comment in this file with "#" before a line, so, my installationhelper should check, if there is a "#" as first character of a line, and if so, just show the comment, but ignore the line otherwise. So far, I'm strugling to get it to work as discribed, I feel like I'm missing something small.

My Codesnipet

```
cat $PATHTOLIBRARIESFILE | while read line; do
    $temp = $line
    if [[ "${a:0:1}" == "#" ]]; then
       echo "$line"
       echo "This is a comment and will be ignored"
    else
       echo "Installing $line..."
       sudo apt-get install $line -y || exit
    fi
```

This is an example of the textfile

```
#Test1 <--This Line should be ignored for apt-get
curl
libboost-all-dev
libboost-chrono-dev
libboost-chrono1.49-dev
libboost-chrono1.49.0
libboost-date-time-dev
libboost-date-time1.49-dev
libboost-date-time1.49.0
libboost-dev
#Test2 <--This Line should be ignored for apt-get
libboost-filesystem-dev
libboost-filesystem1.49-dev
libboost-filesystem1.49.0
libboost-graph-dev
```

Comment: Your problem would be better solved by creating a simple Debian package which `Depends:` on the other packages you want installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `${a:0:1}` with `${line:0:1}` (there's no variable $a anywhere).

Also, remove the `$temp = $line` line. In an assignment, there are no spaces around the equals sign, and the left hand side variable has no dollar sign - but you don't use $temp anywhere, anyway.

Comment: Thank you, it does now exactly what I intended.